# Releasing memory held in objects in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using a 3rd party DLL from pdf-tools to parse PDF files inside my VB.NET application and write the extracted data to a SQL localDB database. I'm giving the user two options: to select a PDF file for parsing or to point to a folder and the application will loop through all PDF files inside it. Both options call the same procedure doPDFFile() as below.

The problem is: if I import a number of files individually by selecting a file every time, the program runs fine. However, If I select a folder that contains the same files, the memory used by the program will keep growing further and further. In Windows task manager, it can reach to 1 GB after importing around 30 files.

I used ANTS memory profiler from redgate, and it showed that one object called "GraphicsState" which is part of the pdf-tools object is growing too big when looping inside a folder. This does not happen if I select the same files one by one. Besides the memory problem, the application becomes very slow after parsing some files. My questions is: why is this happening? and how to prevent it? The user should be able to point the program to a folder with hundreds of PDF files, how can I achieve this?

Below is a snapshot of the code:

```
'When user selects one file
Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(...) 
   OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
   doPDFFile()
End Sub

'When user selects a folder
Private Sub LoopToolStripMenuItem_Click() Handles LoopToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    sPath = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    For Each fileName As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(...)
        sPath = fileName
        doPDFFile()
    Next
End Sub
```

Inside the doPDFFile() procedure, I'm doing the following, I'm using the document object from pdf-tools and I'm passing it byRef to another procedure:

```
Public Sub doPDFFile()
   Using document As New Pdftools.PdfExtract.Document
       document.open(sPath)
       findFirstPage(document) 'passing by reference
       ParseFirstPage(document) 'passing by reference

      'storing the parsed text in an array
      '.......

       do
          'extracting the colors from the graphicsStateObject inside the document object:
           Using objGraphicsState As Pdftools.PdfExtract.GraphicsState = content.GraphicsState
               sColor = objGraphicsState.FillColorRGB
           End Using
           'save text and color in an array of objects
       until endOfText
   end using
end sub
```

Comment: Do you manipulate `document` in any way? Setting the reference to `null` manually can prevent the using block to call `Dispose()`
On the other hand parhaps Document.Dispose() is not implemented properly. 
Parhaps try to add a `GC.Collect()` after the `doPDFFile()` call in your loop.

Comment: I'm only reading from document and not setting it to null manually.

Comment: If document.dispose is not implemented properly then why is it not causing problems when I call the files individually? I did try gc.collect() in the loop as mentioned but it didn't do any difference. Thanks.

Comment: Parhaps consider updating your 3rd party library? I failed to reproduce the error (memory leak) with `PdfExtractNET` version 4.3.28.0

Comment: I'm using the latest library. I contact 3-Heights and they couldn't reproduce the problem as well. I couldn't send them the entire project though; I only sent a small portion of it. I'm still confused as when I run the entire project on my machine, the memory in Windows task manager jumps above 1 GB after sometime and the program becomes extremely slow.

Comment: You could use the [debugdiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336) tool in order to search for the root of the problem. It has the option to run a diagnostic looking for memory and handle leaks. The diagnosis may tell you where the excess memory actually is allocated.